# Assigning a value to all imported data from CSV in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am relatively new to rails development and would appreciate some guidance.

I have an application where I am importing data from a CSV file. My goal is to assign a value to the imported CSV (Move ID) to group all the imported data.

For example (what I currently have working). I have a group of employees needing to move to a new location, I have a table called Move which has_many employee_moves (another table). I have a collection_select where I can pick from Move_IDs that exist. I can also import a CSV file where I am assigning each row to my existing Employee_Move table.

I would like, if possible, to be able to select a Move_ID, select my CSV file to import and associate each record from the CSV file to my selected Move_ID. Essentially assigning that CSV of employees moving to a specific move.

I am able to assign these values manually one at a time once imported in a edit view using a partial I have created.

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

I hope that this is all making sense...

I have been trying to solve this for a while now so please excuse (and feel free to point out) any redundant code that may be remaining from my previous attempts.

**EmployeeMove Model**

```
  require 'csv'

  attr_accessor :move

  belongs_to :move, optional: true
  belongs_to :location, optional: true

  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: false) do |row|
      EmployeeMove.create!({
        :person => row[1],
        :from_building => row[2],
        :from_floor => row[3],
        :from_room => row[4],
        :to_building => row[5],
        :to_floor => row[6],
        :to_room => row[7],
        :notes => row[8],
        :move_id => move.id   <-- I know this is my problem.
        })
    end
  end
```

**EmployeeMovesController**

```
class EmployeeMovesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @employee_moves = EmployeeMove.all
  end

  def new
    @employee_move = EmployeeMove.new
  end

  def create
    @employee_move = EmployeeMove.new(employee_move_params)
    if @employee_move.save
      flash[:notice] = "Employee Move successfully added"
      redirect_to employee_move_path(@employee_move)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @employee_move = EmployeeMove.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @employee_move = EmployeeMove.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @employee_move = EmployeeMove.find(params[:id])
    if @employee_move.update(employee_move_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Emplyee Move successfully updated"
      redirect_to employee_move_path(@employee_move)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def import
    EmployeeMove.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to employee_moves_path, notice: "CSV Imported."
  end


  private
  def employee_move_params
    params.require(:employee_move).permit(:id, :person, :from_building, :from_floor, :from_room, :to_building, :to_floor, :to_room, :comments, :notes,
                                          :Complete, :move_id, :location_id)
  end

end
```

**My Collection_Select**

Currently located in the new and edit pages of Employee Move, also using a _form partial.

```
<%= form_for @employee_move do |f| %>

<p>
  <%= f.label :Move_ID %>&nbsp
  <%= collection_select(:employee_move, :move_id, Move.all, :id, :id, { :prompt => true }, { :multiple => false} ) %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :employee_move_name %>&nbsp
  <%= f.text_field :person %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :From_Building %>&nbsp
  <%= f.text_field :from_building %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :From_Floor %>&nbsp
  <%= f.text_field :from_floor %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :From_Room %>&nbsp
  <%= f.text_field :from_room %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :To_Building %>&nbsp
  <%= f.text_field :to_building %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :To_Floor %>&nbsp
  <%= f.text_field :to_floor %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :To_Room %>&nbsp
  <%= f.text_field :to_room %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :Comment %>&nbsp
  <%= f.text_field :comments %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :Note %>&nbsp
  <%= f.text_field :notes %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.submit %>
</p>

<% end %>
```

A thought while writing this, I would prefer for my CSV import to be located in my Move show page (not meaning Employee Move show page). I currently have a Move index page where I can select from a list of created moves. Selecting a move from this list I can see the move details followed by a table populated with every Employee part of that move. This is currently working, but like I stated before, only if I manually assign the Move_ID to an employee after the CSV file has been imported.

## =======================================================

**Update**

Thanks Simple Lime for the help thus far. The following are the suggested changes. As I mention in my comment below, I get a `"undefined method 'import' for # <Move:0x00000004388a20>"` currently. These are the changes I have made since my original post.

**Import Method**

I have moved my import method from my EmployeeMoveController to my MoveController.

```
  def import
    @move = Move.find(params[:move_id])
    @move.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to moves_path(@move), notice: "CSV Imported."
  end
```

**Rake Routes**

```
  import_moves POST   /moves/import(.:format)            moves#import
   move_import GET    /moves/:move_id/import(.:format)   moves#import
```

I manually added the second route "move_import", but since the original (import_moves) also points to the same Controller#Action, maybe there is some form of conflict happening here? I'm not sure.

The following code in my Move show page correctly directs me to the correct URL, /moves/1/import.

```
<%= link_to "Add Employees to Move", move_import_path(@move.id) %>
```

**Employee Move Model**

I have removed the `:move_id => move.id`.

```
class EmployeeMove < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'csv'

   attr_accessor :move

  belongs_to :move, optional: true
  belongs_to :location, optional: true

  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: false) do |row|
      self.employee_moves.create!({
        :person => row[1],
        :from_building => row[2],
        :from_floor => row[3],
        :from_room => row[4],
        :to_building => row[5],
        :to_floor => row[6],
        :to_room => row[7],
        :notes => row[8]
        })
    end
  end
end
```

**Import View (html)**

My import.html.erb file is located in /views/employee_moves.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="panel panel-default ">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <h1>move</h1>
        <h1>Move</h1>
      <p>
        Move ID:
        <%= @move.id if @move%>
      </p>

      <%= form_tag import_employee_moves_path, multipart: true do %>
        <%= file_field_tag :file %>
        <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
      <% end %>

      <%= link_to "All Moves", moves_path %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope that this update explains well enough the current state of my problem. Please let me know if anymore information would be required.

Again! Thank you for all the help and patience with my learning.

============================================================

**Final Changes that got this working me for me**

I moved my self.import from my Employee_Move model to my Move model and removed self, making it an instance method.

I changed the `get 'import'` in my routes.rb to `post 'import'`

Hope this is of help to anyone with the problem I've had. Thanks again to Simple Lime for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, assuming I understand everything correctly, you have a 2 models `Move` and `EmployeeMove`. You want to be able to upload a CSV from the `Move` show page and parse that CSV, creating an `EmployeeMove` record for each row in the CSV and the `Move` whose page you are currently on.

To do this, I would first move `EmployeeMove.import` into `Move#import` (so, an instance method on the `Move` model instead of a class method on `EmployeeMove`). Then, since you mention `Move` has_many employee_moves, instead of `EmployeeMove.create!({...})`, you can do

```
self.employee_moves.create!({...})
```

and not need the `:move_id => move.id` line in the create anymore

Lastly, move the `import` method from the `EmployeeMovesController` into `MovesController` and change the route in `config/routes.rb` to look more like `/moves/:id/import` (the only important part here is that it goes to the `MovesController` and has an `:id` for which move it's importing to. Then your import method on the controller should look something like

```
def import
  @move = Move.find(params[:id])
  @move.import(params[:file]) # been a while since I've done a file upload, but I assume params[:file] is working here
  redirect_to moves_path(@move) # or wherever you'd like to send them
end
```

and that should do it for ya. Let me know if I misunderstood your problem or you want something clarified further.

Comment: So I had to leave State for work for a couple weeks, so I apologise in advance for the delay in my response. My current URI Pattern for moves#import is /moves/import(.:format). How can I change that to it passes the id to resembles your advice, /moves/:id/import. Thanks

Comment: if you have a `resources :moves` you can `resources :moves do; post "import", on: :member; end` otherwise you can just do `post "/moves/:id/import", to: "moves#import"`

Comment: I have successfully added the POST to my routes using the resources method you shared with me. However I'm getting a 'No route matches [GET] "import/1/import' error. I see that I only have a POST method in my routes. I get this error from clicking a link on my moves show page '<%= link_to "Add Employees to Move", import_move_path(@move) %>', I also moved my import.html.erb from my Employee_Move views folder to my Move folder. Just giving you the full update on the changes I have made so far.

Comment: So I am still having trouble with this and still getting my issue described above. If you could spare the time, I would really appreciate the help greatly.

Comment: I am getting "undefined method 'import' for #<Move:0x007f2194703e80>" from the `@move.import(params[:file])` in the import function you provided.   I appreciate that it has been some time since you have dealt with file uploads, but do you have any idea why this would be occurring and a way to circumvent this? Thanks again!

Comment: I'd have to see the updated code as it is now, but make sure the `import` method is an instance method on `Move` instead of a class method, if you have any further questions, you should ask a new question and post the current code so that others can see what you've got and might be able to help you out as well

Comment: I have provided an update to my original question. If there is another means for you to look at my code I would be happy to work something out (screenshare or something). Thanks

Comment: you're `def self.import` method is still a class method on `EmployeeMove`, it should be an instance method `def import` on `Move` and then get rid of the `import_moves` route (leaving only the second one you posted) since you'll need a `params[:move_id]` in the action (though if you want to keep it, you could have it passed in as a query param, but that seems redundant)

Comment: So I had to do one more thing after moving my import to Move, change my import GET to a POST in my routes and everything works! Thanks so much for all your help! Not all heroes wear capes...